# Call a function inside a controller from observer in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller like this

```
App.TestController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    navigation:[],
    somefunc:function(){
      //do something
    }
});
```

and have an observer for

```
globalvars = Ember.Object.create({
    page : 1,
});

globalvars.addObserver('page', function() {
    this.get('controller.controllers.Test').somefunc();
});
```

the problem is that i can't call the function inside the controller.

Comment: i don't know if there's anything else wrong, but in `this.get('controller.controllers.Test').somefunc();` "test" needs to be lowercased, i think.

Comment: TypeError: this.get(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

this.get('controller.controllers.test').somefunc(); I am getting this error

Comment: You should explain in more detail, what you are trying to accomplish. You are trying to access the controller in a strange way. Not every Ember Object has to access to each controller. Your approach cannot work.

Comment: the work is to call a function when user clicks a anchor and populate data to the site using ajax. I am trying to set a variables value when user clicks on anchor and call this function to do ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already mentioned in my comment, here a disclaimer:

> You should explain in more detail, what you are trying to accomplish.
>   You are trying to access the controller in a strange way.

But here is an approach if you absolutely have to do it this way:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});
// put the global vars into the App object instead of polluting the global namespace
App.globalvars = Ember.Object.create({
    page : 1,
});
```

Instead of putting the observer in the globalVars object, i would declare the observer in the controller:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    navigation:[],
    somefunc:function(){
      //do something
    },
    globalVarsPageObserver : function(){
        this.somefunc();
    }.observes("App.globalvars.page")
});
```